# PrintWriter overwrite data

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

I'm trying to keep track of a high score in a game I'm making by doing:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("path"));
while(gameLoop) {
    out.write(highScore);
    out.flush();
}
```

It keeps appending the data to the end of the file. I am aware I could `out.close();` and then `out = new PrintWriter(new File("path"));` but that seems like a lot of excess code. Constantly closing and re-opening the file to achieve overwrite. Is there any way for my `PrintWriter` to overwrite the data without closing and re-opening the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest you use `print` (or `println`) with a `PrintWriter`. Next, if I understand your question, you could use a [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and something like

```
while (gameLoop) {
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("path"))) {
        out.println(highScore);
    }
}
```

which will `close` and re-open the `PrintWriter` on every iteration of the loop. Alternatively, you could use nio and something like

```
Path file = Paths.get("path");  
while (gameLoop) {
    byte[] buf = String.valueOf(highScore).getBytes();
    Files.write(file, buf);
}
```

Comment: Well I was hoping to avoid the constant closing and re-opening of the file because I feel like that just adds overhead but maybe not. Either way it solves my problem. The nio solution might be more what I'm looking for though.